# What does z-score mean in Boruta

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, z-score, boruta

The boruta algorithm performs the following steps. ([here](https://www.listendata.com/2017/05/feature-selection-boruta-package.html)). Can anyone explain me what exactly the **z-score** means in this context?

I am referring to point 5 and 6 in the following list. I only know the general formula of the z-score: $z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

> 1.Create duplicate copies of all independent variables. When the number of independent variables in the original data is less than 5, create at least 5 copies using existing variables.
>
> 2.Shuffle the values of added duplicate copies to remove their correlations with the target variable. It is called shadow features or permuted copies.
>
> 3.Combine the original ones with shuffled copies
>
> 4.Run a random forest classifier on the combined dataset and performs a variable importance measure (the default is Mean Decrease Accuracy) to evaluate the importance of each variable where higher means more important.
>
> 5.Then Z score is computed. It means mean of accuracy loss divided by standard deviation of accuracy loss.
>
> 6.Find the maximum Z score among shadow attributes (MZSA)
>
> 7.Tag the variables as 'unimportant'  when they have importance significantly lower than MZSA. Then we permanently remove them from the process.
>
> 8.Tag the variables as 'important'  when they have importance significantly higher than MZSA.
>
> 9.Repeat the above steps for predefined number of iterations (random forest runs), or until all attributes are either tagged 'unimportant' or 'important', whichever comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the second chapter of the [Feature Selection with the Boruta Package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i11/) paper by Kursa and Rudnicki:

> Boruta algorithm is a wrapper built around the random forest
>   classification algorithm [...] It is an
>   ensemble method in which classification is performed by voting of
>   multiple unbiased weak classifiers — decision trees. These trees are
>   independently developed on different bagging samples of the training
>   set. The importance measure of an attribute is obtained as the loss of
>   accuracy of classification caused by the random permutation of
>   attribute values between objects. It is computed separately for all
>   trees in the forest which use a given attribute for classification.
>   Then the average and standard deviation of the accuracy loss are
>   computed. Alternatively, the **$Z$ score computed by dividing the
>   average loss by its standard deviation** can be used as the importance
>   measure. Unfortunately the $Z$ score is not directly related to the
>   statistical significance of the feature importance returned by the
>   random forest algorithm, since its distribution is not $N(0, 1)$
>   (Rudnicki, Kierczak, Koronacki, and Komorowski 2006). Nevertheless, in
>   Boruta we use $Z$ score as the importance measure since it takes into
>   account the fluctuations of the mean accuracy loss among trees in the
>   forest.